# Android Studio - ADB or Virtual Device without admin rights

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, admin, android-virtual-device

Due to my business trips, I would use my professional laptop for improving my skills in Android development. I don't have administrator rights, so I installed Android Studio. Sadly, I have 2 kinds of errors :

- *Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.* Intel HAXM is available at
  ...\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager but I'm
  not allowed to launch intelhaxm-android.exe due to non-admin rights.
- My Android device is not recognized by Android Studio but well
  recognized by my laptop. It seems ADB.exe couldn't be installed
  without admin rights.

How can I fix these issues, at least one of them ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Fred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAXM is a system driver that allows you to improve execution speed of Android emulators running an x86 image. For installation admin permission are required this is a fact. No admin permissions means no HAXM and therefore no speed improvements. However the Android emulator works for x86 and ARM virtual devices.

For working with ADB and a real device you need to enable USB debugging on your device and install the Android ADB driver for USB on your computer. The ADB device appears then in the Windows device manager. Usually installing an driver requires admin permissions.

Conclusion: If you really want to do Android development as an admin to perform the necessary changes if you don't have the required permissions.

Comment: Other solution using Eclipse + ADT ? I'm also stuck with Eclipse + ADT : I had 50+ errors like : ...\WorkSpace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.

Comment: No, Eclipse is not a solution. Internally it uses the same tools from Android SDK, therefore you will have the same problems. Additionally Eclipse is no longer supported by Google.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** install ADB **without** administrator rights!There's a trick which I used and it bypasses need to login using administrator account.

1. Open notepad and paste the following text in that file:

   ```
   cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" "%1""
   ```
2. Save as a batch file.
3. Drag the executable you want to launch without admin and drop it onto the batch file.
4. Installation will start and **won't** ask for logging in as administrator!

**P.S:** I have tested this on Windows 10 (Build 10240) by installing ADB drivers and it ridiculously works! However note that, if your setup produces more `exe`s (internally) then this may not work.

Comment: This is not useful. This can let you jump de admin prompt, but, at the end of the day, you haven't got permissions to write to protected folders, such as "Program Files" or "Windows"

Answer (score 1):

There's [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) if you want to use the phone on PC